# How to find the farthest object in a sub array of a array with empty objects?

Tags: javascript

I've got a array of object in which the children got arrays as well:

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Primary",
    "xPoints": [{
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Untitledtest12",
        "type": "custom",
        "description": ""
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "asd",
        "description": "",
        "type": "custom"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "asd",
        "description": "",
        "type": "custom"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "asd123",
        "description": "",
        "type": "custom"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "a",
        "description": "a",
        "type": "custom"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Untitled X Line",
    "xPoints": [
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {
            "id": 0,
             "name": "this is the farthest",
             "type": "custom",
             "description": ""
          },
          {}
    ]
}]
```

what I'm looking for is a way to get the "farthest" of object index on these childrens of the main array

Expected result:
index: 6 from second's "Untitled X Line"

Comment: exactly, I want to know which one is the most nested and its index (count of the objects until there)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yeah I've tried to use reduce, but I haven't found a proper way per se, this gets me the highest non empty objects from both arrays

let highestPlotPointCount = xLines.reduce( (e1, e2) => e1.xPoints.length>e2.xPoints.length ? e1.xPoints.length: e2.xPoints.length );

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to get the depth of the object.

```js
const obj = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Primary",
    "xPoints": [{
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Untitledtest12",
        "type": "custom",
        "description": ""
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "asd",
        "description": "",
        "type": "custom"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "asd",
        "description": "",
        "type": "custom"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "asd123",
        "description": "",
        "type": "custom"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "a",
        "description": "a",
        "type": "custom"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Untitled X Line",
    "xPoints": [
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {},
          {
            "id": 0,
             "name": "this is the farthest",
             "type": "custom",
             "description": ""
          },
          {}
    ]
}]

function depthOf(object) {
    var level = 1;
    for(var key in object) {
        if (!object.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        if(typeof object[key] == 'object'){
            var depth = depthOf(object[key]) + 1;
            level = Math.max(depth, level);
        }
    }
    return level;
}

var maxLevels = 0;
var maxObj;
obj.forEach(e => maxLevels < depthOf(e) ? maxObj = e : '');
console.log(maxObj);
```